# Not able to open JBoss "Welcome Page" and Console

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I have been working on `IBM WebSphere` Application Server, and wanted to learn `JBoss`.

I have installed `JBoss` properly, but not able to open the “Welcome Page” & Console. Need you help here.

Actually I connect to a server – let say, ABC from my machine(X). That ABC server is linux box and I connect via putty from my machine(X).

I have installed `Jboss` and JDK on that ABC server and when I run the `standalone.sh` command and try to open welcome page from my machine(X) – http://ABC:8080. Nothing comes up.

The same ABC server has `IBM WebSphere` installed in it. If the secure admin port, let say is 9061, I am able to open IBM Console from my machine(X) with – https://ABC:9061/ibm/console.

My point is there any configuration file in `JBoss`, were i have to mention this server name – ABC. I guess hope u got my point here. Do let me know in case u didn’t understood my query.

Output of my `standalone.sh` script:

```
[root@ABC bin]# ./standalone.sh –server-config=standalone-full-ha.xml

=========================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /opt/JBoss/Wildfly8/wildfly-8.0.0.Final

JAVA: /opt/JBoss/java7/7.0_SR9_FP20l64/jre/bin/java

JAVA_OPTS: -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

12:22:02,695 INFO [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final
12:22:02,911 INFO [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.0.Final
12:22:02,999 INFO [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.0.0.Final “WildFly” starting
12:22:04,707 INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
12:22:04,725 INFO [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
12:22:04,738 INFO [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
12:22:04,770 INFO [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool — 56) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
12:22:04,781 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups] (ServerService Thread Pool — 43) JBAS010260: Activating JGroups subsystem.
12:22:04,786 INFO [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool — 39) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
12:22:04,788 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool — 38) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
12:22:04,812 INFO [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool — 51) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
12:22:04,821 INFO [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.20.Final
12:22:04,830 INFO [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool — 46) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
12:22:04,842 INFO [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool — 60) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
12:22:04,886 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.3.Final)
12:22:04,928 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool — 59) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
12:22:04,930 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
12:22:04,988 INFO [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
12:22:04,999 INFO [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
12:22:05,002 INFO [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
12:22:05,012 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool — 33) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
12:22:05,024 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
12:22:05,196 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool — 59) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path /opt/JBoss/Wildfly8/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/welcome-content
12:22:05,213 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
12:22:05,243 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
12:22:05,323 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017519: Undertow AJP listener ajp listening on /127.0.0.1:8009
12:22:05,333 INFO [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) MODCLUSTER000001: Initializing mod_cluster version 1.3.0.Final
12:22:05,335 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0.0.1:8080
12:22:05,389 INFO [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) MODCLUSTER000032: Listening to proxy advertisements on /224.0.1.105:23364
12:22:05,517 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221000: live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=true,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=/opt/JBoss/Wildfly8/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/data/messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=/opt/JBoss/Wildfly8/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/data/messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/opt/JBoss/Wildfly8/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/data/messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=/opt/JBoss/Wildfly8/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/data/messagingpaging)
12:22:05,545 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221006: Waiting to obtain live lock
12:22:05,656 INFO [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
12:22:05,657 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221012: Using AIO Journal
12:22:05,796 INFO [io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system unstability.
12:22:05,855 INFO [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016328: CORBA Naming Service started
12:22:05,866 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
12:22:05,885 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221043: Adding protocol support CORE
12:22:05,895 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221043: Adding protocol support AMQP
12:22:05,898 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221043: Adding protocol support STOMP
12:22:05,980 INFO [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services – Stack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final
12:22:05,989 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221034: Waiting to obtain live lock
12:22:05,990 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
12:22:05,994 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/JBoss/Wildfly8/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments
12:22:06,327 INFO [org.jboss.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011615: Registered HTTP upgrade for hornetq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
12:22:06,328 INFO [org.jboss.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011615: Registered HTTP upgrade for hornetq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
12:22:06,447 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221007: Server is now live
12:22:06,447 INFO [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.4.1.Final (Fast Hornet, 124) [f0d6d0ea-a8cd-11e5-b68a-d1ffaffdeb86]
12:22:06,464 INFO [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool — 62) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
12:22:06,465 INFO [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool — 63) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
12:22:06,512 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
12:22:06,568 INFO [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-4) HornetQ resource adaptor started
12:22:06,569 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-4) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
12:22:06,571 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
12:22:06,571 INFO [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
12:22:06,645 INFO [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
12:22:06,645 INFO [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:22:06,646 INFO [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.0.0.Final “WildFly” started in 4521ms – Started 229 of 356 services (172 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, WildFly only binds to the local network interface.

This can be seen in your log:

```
JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0.0.1:8080
JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
```

Use the `-b` and `-bmanagement` options of `standalone.sh` to bind to `ABC` or to all network interfaces, e.g.

```
standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Also, if you want to change network interfaces constantly, you have to edit interfaces tag on configuration file(its path is probably that "WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml") of your WildFly server.

Comment: Binding to 0.0.0.0 is not a good practise. It renders mod_cluster unusable for most production scenarios (it reports 127.0.0.1 to the balancer) and might have other side effects.

Comment: @ Sevan Nerse : Yes i tried that too & it worked. Now i don't have to pass the values everytime with standalone script

Answer (score 0):

- check the log as to where are connectors and console listening
- bind the server to the desired IP address
- in dynamic environments, one might want to find the address first according to the interface name, e.g. something along (depends on the system, Fedora 22 Docker image):
  `` MYIP="`networkctl status ${DESIRED_NIC:-eth0} | awk '{if($1~/Address:/){printf($2);}}'`" ``

  and then

  `-Djboss.bind.address.management=${MYIP}
  -Djboss.bind.address=${MYIP}`